# How can I store player infor into a file if I want to build the game for Windowsphone 8 platform

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm buiding an Unity 2d game, I want to store some thing like "playerlevel,score,playerName..." into a file, I'm using "System.IO" but it just work when I build the game for android platform, someone told me the "System.IO" not available for WindowsPhone platform because It was replaced by the "Windows.Storage API", so can anyone tell me, is there some other way to store Data into a file or how can I using the "System.storage"?

Comment: There is a good tutorial at the live training archive on this topic.
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/persistence-data-saving-loading
As far as I know you don't have to worry about the platform. Unity will use the default folder for such information on a device.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use built-in `PlayerPrefs`? You can basically store there `float/int/string` values, and it is platform independent. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

If you need to save more data types you can serialize it yourself or use some extensions like [ArrayPrefs](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ArrayPrefs2). It is also good to store sensitive data using some kind of encryption, again written by yourself, or with use of any Crypted Player Prefs package on the Unity Asset Store, there are many of them.